# Force Angular app to redirect when session expired

Tags: node.js, angular, express, openid-connect

I have an Angular app which requires session authorization from an OIDC service. With the normal/happy path, a separate NodeJS/Express app checks for session authorization and redirects to the OIDC authorization/authentication service and attaches the relevant headers. If everything passes, the middleware routes to the Angular app.

At a point though, the Angular app runs with a token that is expired. The Angular app gets the username and at that point I could check for expiration. However, if it is expired, I need the Angular way to react to the error condition by re-routing the whole Angular app to the relevant middleware page. Because the indicator will go to a component nested within the app, I don't know how to get the little component to redirect the bigger/encompassing app.

I'm not an Angular person, so I don't even know what part of Angular to look up. Because of my lack of knowledge, I'm including source files that might or might not be relevant.

header.component.ts is where it gets the username and could return a bad token indicator

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../../../core/services/profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'header-comp',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  userName: string = 'No Session';

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onDisplayUserLogged();
  }

  onDisplayUserLogged() {
    this.profileService.getUsername().subscribe(data => {
      this.userName = 'Welcome: ' + data;
    });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

//Services
import { ProfileService } from './core/services/profile.service';
import { FinanceService } from './core/services/finance.service';
import { CmasService } from './core/services/cmas.service';
import { SoftlayerService } from './core/services/softlayer.service';
import { DashboardService } from './core/services/dashboard.service';
import { LowDollarExceptionService } from './core/services/lowDollarException.service';

//Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CmasComponent } from './modules/cmas/cmas.component';
import { SoftlayerComponent } from './modules/softlayer/softlayer.component';
import { FinanceComponent } from './modules/finance/finance.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './modules/error/error/error.component';
import { LowDollarExceptionComponent } from './modules/lowDollarException/lowDollarException.component'
import { MenuComponent } from './shared/layout/menu/menu.component';
import { BasicComponent } from './shared/modals/basic/basic.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/layout/header/header.component';
import { PreProcessedPipe } from './shared/components/file-listing/file-listing.component';
import { ProcessedPipe } from './shared/components/softlayer-file-list/softlayer-file-list.component';

//Routing
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

//Libs
import { AuthInterceptor } from 'auth-lib';
import { TermsComponent } from './modules/terms/terms.component';
import { FileListingComponent } from './shared/components/file-listing/file-listing.component';
import { ConfirmCancelComponent } from './shared/modals/confirm-cancel/confirm-cancel.component';
import { ErrorDisplayComponent } from './shared/components/error-display/error-display.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './modules/about/about.component';
import { ResultsComponent } from './modules/cmas/results/results.component';
import { SoftlayerFileListComponent } from './shared/components/softlayer-file-list/softlayer-file-list.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './modules/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ReviewResultsComponent } from './modules/softlayer/review-results/review-results.component';
import { InvoiceDetailsComponent } from './modules/dashboard/invoice-details/invoice-details.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LowDollarNewRecordComponent } from './modules/lowDollarException/lowDollarNewRecord.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CmasComponent,
    FinanceComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    BasicComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    FileListingComponent,
    PreProcessedPipe,
    ProcessedPipe,
    ConfirmCancelComponent,
    ErrorDisplayComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ResultsComponent,
    SoftlayerComponent,
    SoftlayerFileListComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ReviewResultsComponent,
    InvoiceDetailsComponent,
    LowDollarExceptionComponent,
    LowDollarNewRecordComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [
    ProfileService,
    FinanceService,
    CmasService,
    SoftlayerService,
    DashboardService,
    LowDollarExceptionService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      deps: [Router],
      multi: true,
    },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/sprint-cost-recovery' },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import listadeTerms from '../assets/config/properties.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.openOverlay();
  }

  openOverlay() {
    var sheet = document.createElement('style');
    sheet.innerHTML =
      '.ds-full-width {visibility: hidden;} .usabilla_live_button_container{visibility: hidden;}';
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
    if (document.getElementById('termsDialog')) {
      var overlayElement = document.querySelector('#termsDialog');
      overlayElement.classList.add('ds-open');
      document
        .querySelector('#termsDialogCloseBtn')
        .addEventListener('click', load);
    }
    function load() {
      var div = document.getElementById('termsDialog');
      sheet.innerHTML = '.usabilla_live_button_container{visibility: true;}';
      var parent = div.parentElement;
      parent.removeChild(div);
      var node = sheet.parentNode;
      node.removeChild(sheet);
    }
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// Components
import { CmasComponent } from './modules/cmas/cmas.component';
import { FinanceComponent } from './modules/finance/finance.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './modules/error/error/error.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './modules/about/about.component';
import { SoftlayerComponent } from './modules/softlayer/softlayer.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './modules/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LowDollarExceptionComponent } from './modules/lowDollarException/lowDollarException.component';
import { LowDollarNewRecordComponent } from './modules/lowDollarException/lowDollarNewRecord.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'finance', component: FinanceComponent },
  { path: 'cmas-process', component: CmasComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'softlayer-process', component: SoftlayerComponent },
  { path: 'cost-dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'low-dollar', component: LowDollarExceptionComponent },
  { path: 'low-dollar/create', component: LowDollarNewRecordComponent },
  { path: 'error/auth', component: ErrorComponent, data: { forbidden: true } },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/finance', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'error/badgateway',
    component: ErrorComponent,
    data: { badgateway: true },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this in Angular is through the [Route Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access). At a high level, it was like so:

1. Create the [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access). It returns a true or false depending on a condition it checks.
2. Add the canActivate parameter to the routes that need to be checked for authentication, e.g.:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'finance', component: FinanceComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'cmas-process', component: CmasComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

3. If the user is not authenticated, the redirect (to the login page for example) is specified in the route guard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private logger: NGXLogger,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivateChild(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      map(isLoggedIn => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          return this.router.parseUrl('/login');
        }

        return true;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to mark the above answer as correct. I got the rough idea I was hoping for. But I have to ask a follow up question. If I'm authenticating using Passport on a separate Node/Express server, which Angular package should I include to check isAuthenticated() and then redirect to the login page?

Comment: For that, at a high-level, you would create a service that makes the HTTP call to get the response from the express server, and return the value in isAuthenticated() accordingly. There are a number of articles available for "angular login example" @Woodsman